# What is difference between mild ,modest and moderate?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

As often seen in different stats especially in context of covid-19,some times we see term "mild" and sometime "moderate"
One more apparently same term althought not in context of covid specifically, is "modest

What is exactly difference between all three?mild vs modest vs moderate?

Comment: A dictionary would seem to be a good starting point

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mild generally means something you’d rather not happen but can safely ignore (though with covid-19 I personally wouldn’t consider anything “safe”) and Moderate is something you should definitely take seriously but not there is no need for panic or stress.

Modest has very similar meaning to moderate, perhaps a little less but close enough that you’d really have to ask for clarification to determine the difference between “modest” and “moderate”.

As another example:

A “mild” burn would be if you set the shower temperature a bit too hot and experienced pain for a few seconds. A moderate or modest burn would be more like spilling boiling water on yourself while cooking - it might hurt for half an hour or so but unlikely to cause injury.

Back to covid-19, mild symptoms would be a runny nose and a cough. Moderate or modest symptoms would be headaches, fatigue, etc.

Comment: We wouldn't use _modest_ in this context. It's normally used to describe something which is small but adequate for the purpose (a modest income, a modest amount of food, a modest improvement).

Comment: @KateBunting I wouldn't use it either, but people in the media are doing so. The Washington Post for example. If it fits their style guidelines, then clearly a lot of people would use it in this context and it's fair enough for someone learning english to ask what the word means in that unusual context.